# Проблема при копировании таблицы PostgreSQL

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, intellij-idea, запрос

Создал таблицу с serial primary key. Вторую создал как копию с with no data.
Из первой таблицы копирую строки во вторую, но вот поле с serial primary key не генерируется.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpDDt.png]

Поле sickid копируется как есть.
Помогите, как исправить?
и еще такой вопрос...
Пользуюсь statment.executeQuerry(SQL);
Но вот беда, переменные постоянно очищаются.
Например:

```
String SQL = "select * from "+firstName+"_"+lastName+"  where sickid=";
result = statement.executeQuery(SQL + j);
nameOf=result.getString("name");
```

Каждый раз по разному, бывает переменная успевает отрабатывать, бывает что в дебаге при переходе на следующую строчку она сразу теряет свое значение. Как исправить?
Добавлял

```
result.next();
```

Но положение не особо меняется

Answer (score 0):

Пытался так же делать что то вроде:

```
String s = statement.executeQuery(SQL+j).getString(2);
```

Но выдает ошибку с подсказкой:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.
```